# Watcher does not work when passing data from for loop from the parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

```
<div v-for= "(item , index) in chartData"  class="col" :key="index">
  <ColumnChart
    :chartdata="item.tactical"
    :simpletype="true"
  />
</div>
```

My `chartData` is a property which contains an empty array.

After a server request is populated with an Array of Objects.

In the for loop above, i'm passing those data to the child component called "ColumnChart".

My problem, is that the watcher of the child component seems that its not working correctly.

```
 watch: {
        chartdata(val) { 
            console.log(val) // This val never appears in the console
            if (val !== null) {
                this.initChart();
            }

            if (val.length === 0) {
                this.initLoading();
            }

        },
    },
```

What is really strange is that the props of the child component are filled with the data from the parent.

Moreover when i'm passing the data directly without using a loop, everything is working fine.

```
<ColumnChart
  :chartdata="chartData.length > 0 ? chartData[0].tactical : []"
  :simpletype="true"
/>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `chartData(val)`, not `chartdata(val)`. Is it a typo?

Comment: @fabruex It's not a problem - watcher is inside child component `ColumnChart` which has a prop `chartdata`

Comment: have you tried to add `immediate: true` to the watcher?

Comment: use vue.set or array.splice to update arrays - else not reactive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could catch the new values using `mounted`. As I am assuming when you first initialise the `for` loop, the array is empty (so no elements exist yet). Then once the data from the server arrives, it creates each element. Therefore, the `watchers` are not yet in place (don't exist) and that is why they do not fire.

```js
mounted() {
    console.log('inside mounted', this.chartdata);
},
```

If you want to watch for futures changes you can still add a watcher too

```js
watch: {
    chartdata: function(value) {
      console.log("new val", value);
    }
  }
```

Now if the array changes for existing entries, the watcher will fire.

This also explains why this works:

```html
<ColumnChart
      :chartdata="chartData.length > 0 ? chartData[0].tactical : []"
      :simpletype="true"
    />
```

In this case, the element does exists, and the watcher is initialised.

**EDIT**

As @fabruex suggested. You could add the `immediate: true` flag to the watcher as an alternative. This will have the effected of triggering the watcher automatically on mount by default:

```
watch: {
    chartdata: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(value) {
        console.log("new val", value);
      },
    },
  }
```

Comment: `immediate` watchers are fired on created (before `created` hook of component is fired) imho. Otherwise I agree with analysis...

Comment: Hello! You are right! The Component is not created until indeed the loop is running! Both ways work! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your watcher configuration, it should be `chartData` instead of `chartdata`.

Comment: It's not a problem - watcher is inside child component `ColumnChart` which has a prop `chartdata`